# windows 8.1 update failed error 0xc1900101-0x2000c

Tags: installation, windows-8.1

I wanted to update my win8 to win8.1 but the installation fails and gives me error 0xc1900101-0x2000c. I searched a lot about this but I only got answers for error 0xC1900101 - 0x40017 but that too is not helpful.
(HP Pavilion G6-2312AX AMD A10-4600M APU. 2.30 GHz & 4GB RAM)
Need Help for the fix.
Thank You

Comment: This is not a computer programming question

Comment: [Errors 0xC1900101 0x2000C while updating from 8 to 8.1 on Win-Store](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/errors-0xc1900101-0x2000c-while-updating-from-8-to/de3f9685-f299-4025-9c4b-fb649ae6be1e)

Comment: [Install Windows 8.1 failed because of error 0xC1900101-0x2000C](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/install-windows-81-failed-because-of-error/47cf40aa-e3c2-45bc-a057-70f3a50ef0e3)